# How to skip for_each loop if key does not exist in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-github

My problem statement is simple but I am not able to find a solution anywhere on the internet.

I have users list as `locals`:

```
// users

locals {
  allUsers = {

    dev_user_1 = {
      Name   = "user1"
      Email  = "user1@abc.com"
      GitHub = "user1" # github username
      Team   = "Dev"
    }

    devops_user_2 = {
      Name   = "user2"
      Email  = "user2@abc.com"
      GitHub = "user2" # github username
      Team   = "DevOps"
    }

    product_user_3 = {
      Name   = "user3"
      Email  = "user3@abc.com"
      Team   = "Product"
    }
  }
}
```

These are the `local` tags that are being used for purposes of creating access to internal tools such as Github, Monitoring tools, etc.

Now, for the 2 users who belong to the `Dev` and `DevOps` team, they need access to Github ORG, while, the product user only needs access to some dashboards but not to Github, hence, the tag is missing.

How can I loop over the terraform resource `github_membership` to skip this product user (or simply anyone who does not have tag `key` GitHub?)

I am trying the following code, but no luck

```
// Send GitHub invite
resource "github_membership" "xyzTeam" {
  for_each = local.allUsers
  username = each.value.GitHub
  role     = "member"
}
```

Errors:

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on users.tf line 12, in resource "github_membership" "xyzTeam":
│   12:   username = each.value.GitHub
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 3 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "GitHub".
```

#### What I did to solve this issue?

1. Set GitHub `key` for everyone but it's `value` as `null`.
   Error:

```
╷
│ Error: "username": required field is not set
│
│   with github_membership.xyzTeam["user3"],
│   on users.tf line 10, in resource "github_membership" "xyzTeam":
│   10: resource "github_membership" "devops" {
│
╵
```

2. If I left the value empty, errors:

```
Error: PATCH https://api.github.com/user/memberships/orgs/XYZ: 422 You can only update an organization membership's state to 'active'. []
```

3. `for k, v in local.allUsers : k => v if v != ""`
   Same error because it tries to create the user with empty value still, and fails ultimately.

I cannot think of anything else. If someone can help to create separate `locals` from these existing `locals`, which creates the list of `locals` that grep the `GitHub` values, that hack would be super helpful.

Comment: `for_each = {
    for k, v in local.allUsers : k => v if v.GitHub != null
  }`

This is fixing the 50% issue, but I still have to set the tag `GitHub = null`. Not setting this up and making it work would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had the right idea with your third attempt, but the conditional logic in the for expression is slightly off. You need to use the `can` function instead:

```
{ for user, attributes in local.allUsers : user => attributes if can(attributes.GitHub) }
```

If the nested map contains a `Github` key, then `can(attributes.Github)` returns `true`, and the map constructor will contain the key-value pair. With this algorithm, you can construct a new map from the old map with the entries removed that do not contain a `Github` key in the nested map value.

Comment: @AlokKelsey I missed that the variable name was `GitHub` instead of `Github`. I updated the `h` to `H` and it now works correctly. You may want to consider adopting the standard TF style of snake case in the future.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I don't know what wrong I was doing but now it has worked like a charm! Thanks man.

Comment: Yes true, it was typo. We commented at the same time.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again for saving lots of my time 